# How to calculate the product in 1row with 2columns?

Tags: python-2.7

I use Python 2.7

I got a set of data like this in a txt file:

1.0 10.0

2.0 20.0

5.0 50.0

I would like to find the product of all rows (i.e. 10.0 for 1st row, 40 for 2nd row, etc.)

Then, I would like to find the sum of all rows (i.e. 10+40+250)

How to type the codes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are just start your way in python, so although you didn't post any code, this is a simple code that will help you get started, hopefully next time you won't ask the answer upfront and will have more confidence to tackle the problem yourself and than come to stack-overflow for help

```
products = list()

with open('some.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data = line.split()
        if len(data) == 2:
            products.append(float(data[0]) * float(data[1]))

for i,p in enumerate(products):
    print("[{}] {}".format(i,p))
print(sum(products))
```

output

```
[0] 10.0
[1] 40.0
[2] 250.0
300.0
```

Comment: Thank you for helping first. Now I have other questions: I used the text file to write several formula to calculate some values and I want to assign those values to a single variable respectively. Then I want print a sentence with those variables.                   For example:     I made two equations: 1) print x+y  <--let it be A  2) print x*y  <--let it be B   and I got two variables, A and B when I run the code. I want to know how to type the sentence with those assigned variables, like print("The equation is A+100B-5")

Comment: `print("The equation is {}".format(A+100*B-5))` you can get more info here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html